# Validate multiple image size before upload

Tags: jquery, image, validation

i have code to upload multiple image if image size is not valid it not show onload but on click submit button it upload to server i want that image is not upload on serve here is mycode

```
<div class="box-body">
            <form action='myaction' method="post" name="form_dirc" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p id="img_valid"></p>
                <input type="file" id="files"  class="" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" /><br>
                <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-success" style="margin-left:14px;"><b>Upload<b></button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

and here jquery code

```
$("#files").on("change", function (e) {
        var files = e.target.files,
        filesLength = files.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
            $('#img_valid').css('display', 'none');
            var f = files[i]
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (function (e) {
               var file = e.target;
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = e.target.result;
                    var res = null;
                    img.onload = function() {                        
                    if(this.width > 500 && this.height > 500){
                                    $("<img></img>", {
                                class: "imageThumbShow",
                                src: e.target.result,
                                title: file.name
                            }).insertAfter("#files");
                    }
                    else{            
                        $('#img_valid').css('display', 'block');
                        $('#img_valid').html("Image  height width must be min 400px.")
                        return false;
                    }
                    }
            });
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    });
```

i want to remove image from files[] array that is not valid size then upload other image only

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) for uploading file (images), DropzoneJS has many options. one of this options is "maxFilesize" that allow you to limit size of images.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
            if (typeof ($("#fileUpload")[0].files) != "undefined") {
                var size = parseFloat($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
                alert(size + " KB.");
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```